# How to write class definition for this in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement a generic `TableViewDataSource` which can be used by providing an array of ViewModels and each cell should have a `configureCell` method to populate the cell from the provided `ViewModel`.

I think I need to add something more to this line of code

```
class TableViewDataSource<CellType,ViewModel>:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource where CellType: UITableViewCell
```

to access

```
cell.configureCell(withViewModel:items[indexPath.row])
```

This is the entire class for reference:

```
protocol TableCellDelegate {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    func configureCell(withViewModel viewModel:ViewModel)
}

class TableViewDataSource<CellType,ViewModel>:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource where CellType: UITableViewCell {

    var items:[ViewModel]

    init(viewModelItems: [ViewModel]) {
        self.items = viewModelItems
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellType.identifier, for: indexPath) as? CellType else {
            fatalError("Could not initialize cell for identifier \(CellType.identifier)")
        }
        cell.configureCell(withViewModel:items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Since a delegate is supposed to implement `configureCell` it looks like you need to have the cell as an argument in that function. For instance `func configureCell(_ cell: CellType, withViewModel viewModel:ViewModel)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do sth like this

```
import UIKit

class MyViewModel {

}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, TableCellDelegate {
    static var cellIdentifier: String = "id"

    func configureCell(withViewModel viewModel: MyViewModel) {

    }

    typealias ViewModel = MyViewModel


}

protocol TableCellDelegate: UITableViewCell {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    func configureCell(withViewModel viewModel:ViewModel)
    static var cellIdentifier: String {get}
}


class TableViewDataSource<CellType>:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate where CellType: TableCellDelegate {

    var items:[CellType.ViewModel]

    init(viewModelItems: [CellType.ViewModel]) {
        self.items = viewModelItems
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellType.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CellType else {
            fatalError("Could not initialize cell for identifier \(CellType.cellIdentifier)")
        }
        cell.configureCell(withViewModel:items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```